# What term can be used to describe Yoda's speech?

Tags: terminology, speech, fronting

What is Yoda's speech called? Is there a particular name for it (such as "dangling...")?

Comment: [Cross-linking](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25508/is-employing-hyperbaton-correct-in-english) the related question I mentioned.

Comment: It reminds me of the syntax used in Hindi.

Comment: I think Hindi is SOV, subject-object-verb. It sounds a bit similar because the verb is at the end, as in Japanese, and sometimes in German for sentences with two verbs.

Comment: Added '[anastrophe](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/anastrophe.htm)'

Comment: some OSV languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Subject_Verb

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke: "Yes, speak English with a Latin construction I do"

Comment: Please see http://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2015/12/hmmmmm/420798/ and https://theweek.com/articles/442256/why-strangely-yoda-speaks for more.

Answer (score 30):

This is more a linguistics question than an English language question in my opinion.

The quality of Yoda's speech that makes it sound strange to English speakers - and the speakers of the majority of earth's langauges is that it uses a very uncommon linguistic typology or word ordering known as [Object-Subject-Verb (OSV) or sometimes Object-Agent-Verb (OAV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Subject_Verb).

Comment: Correctly you have answered

Comment: This covers some of the patterns of Yodish, but I think you have to qualify it more than that. E.g. consider `Help you I will.` It's a bit of a stretch to analyze that as OSV... you'd have to consider the main verb as the Object, and the auxiliary verb as the verb. That's a plausible analysis, but not the usual one AFAIK, and possibly controversial, so it would need to be mentioned.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes we run into these exact problems when trying to analyse the typology of real languages too. I would suggest that word-order types specifically and linguistic typology generally are nothing more than a rough guide at best. But as I said this is more in the realm of a linguistics topic than an English language topic. As far as the English language is concerned, OSV is probably as good a specific term describing Yodish as we have. The other best answer would be "there's no English word that can accurately capture the quality of Yodishness".

Comment: @hippietr, I think this question is more about English linguistics than about lg typology (and that's why word-order types like "OSV" are a poor fit). Yoda's speech is designed to be understandable but odd for Engl-sp audiences, in a way that matches certain recognizable patterns of Engl speech, and evokes a certain character thereby. So if there is a term in the field of Engl grammar that describes postposing of S and an aux V, as in "(I expected to finish the race, and) **finish I did**", I believe that term would best answer this question.

Comment: @LarsH: There's certainly various ways of thinking about this question. One way is to consider that Yodish in almost not certainly a fully constructed language like Esperanto or Klingon but rather the scriptwriters probably just "exotified" each of Yoda's lines to match a certain unusual sound and in so doing rearranged parts of the sentence without regard to some exact underlying syntactic scheme. On the other hand maybe they did hire a linguist to do a realistic job (-:

Comment: I'm curious about how this form is still entirely comprehensible (and valid?) in English, but what about other languages that have stricter rules? Can it translate?

Comment: @jsj Oddly enough, omitting the subject and simply saying "correctly answered" does not sound strange at all. (OV=OK, OSV=NG ...in English)

Comment: Good answer. According to this http://funtranslations.com/yoda it may not always be OSV.  There are some situations where he may not follow the strict OSV structure.

Comment: It is not that uncommon. Inflected languages where order is redundant often default to SVO or SOV, but in such languages OSV has a long tradition of poetic or rhetorical usage. In many literal translations, Yoda doesn't sound weird, just dramatic (and often even merely thoughtful or old).

Answer (score 18):

[Here is an article on Yoda-speak at the Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002173.html).

> One way to look at Yoda's syntax is that it shows signs of favoring OSV syntax (Object-Subject-Verb) as the basic order in the simple clause. In fact one could call it XSV syntax, where the X is whatever complement would appropriately go with the verb, whether it's an object or not.

And then:

> But there is another way to see Yoda's syntax: you could see him as using SVO (or SVX) but favoring, almost to excess, certain special constructions that English allows only as stylistic variations in special discourse contexts.

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer. See my other comment about "Help you I will." This sentence fits more with "favoring, almost to excess" a special stylistic inversion of sentence constituents ("I knew I was going to miss her. And **miss her I did.**"), than it does with a basic XSV order.

Comment: That is exactly what the author was getting at.

Comment: +1 This is a decent linguistic answer but not really the englishSO answer to "What is Yoda's speech called?".

Comment: @hippietrail https://theweek.com/articles/442256/why-strangely-yoda-speaks is also nice.

Answer (score 14):

Just saw a question about the topic not too long ago ;P

"[Hyperbaton](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/H/hyperbaton.htm) and [Anastrophe](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/anastrophe.htm)"

1. Hyperbaton: An inversion of normal word order. A generic term for a variety of figures involving transposition (see below), it is sometimes synonymous with anastrophe.
2. Anastrophe: Usually synonymous and occasionally referred to as a more specific instance of hyperbaton: the changing of the position of only a single word.

---

This style is found in certain forms of poetry. One example of Yoda's speech, "Sorry, but *go* you must." instead of "Sorry, but you must *go.*" is seen attached to [this small article](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/hyperbatonterm.htm).

> A figure of speech that uses disruption or inversion of customary word order to produce a distinctive effect also, a figure in which language takes a sudden turn--usually an interruption.
>
> Plural: hyperbata. Adjective: hyperbatonic....From the Greek, "passed over, transposed"

---

Here's a small example calling on the same phrase in a technical analogy from the [University of Baltimore](http://iat.ubalt.edu/moulthrop/hypertexts/hoptext/Hyperbaton05865.html)

> Jay Bolter once showed me an interesting approach to the dialectic of singular and multiple sequences in hypertext (1992). He invoked the rhetorical figure of hyperbaton or scrambled syntax -- the way Yoda speaks in the Star Wars movies...
>
> ...in much the same way that we understand what Yoda means when he says, "Sorry I be but go you must." We register the disorder in the text but make sense of it by extrapolating a more conventional pattern.

Comment: A reference would improve this answer.

Comment: Yes, true that is :)

Comment: Giggling I am, that answer for this question my joking was.

Comment: +1 for both providing an alternative answer and providing an English language term that describes it!

Answer (score 4):

here's a fairly thorough discussion of [**Yodish**](http://www.yodajeff.com/pages/talk/yodish.shtml)

> Yodish, the language of Yoda of Star
>   Wars fame is quite similar to that of
>   our standard English. The words he
>   uses are the same as those we use.
>   They are intended to be used for the
>   same purpose or part of speech. His
>   language contains the same phrase
>   structures and if enough applications
>   are made, it is likely that infinite
>   combinations are possible. Yodish is
>   not an arbitrary grammar which simply
>   confuses that of SEV willy-nilly but
>   there is a standard pattern of rules
>   which are applied, though not likely
>   purposefully designed by creator
>   George Lucas. If this were the case,
>   the errors I have mentioned would very
>   likely not exist nor would the fourth
>   class of sentences, that of the SEV
>   structures used for clarity of
>   understanding. There are some
>   exceptions to these rules, but we can
>   apply the rules of Yodish and create
>   an everyday language and therefore,
>   Yodish is a legitimate language, or in
>   the grammar of Yoda, "A legitimate
>   language is Yodish, yes. Hmmm."