# Why do we put subject and auxiliary verbs at the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, british-english, dialects

Why do we put subject and auxiliary verbs e.g., *have*, *be*, *do* at the end of the sentence?
I found this kind of sentences from a fantasy book named The last apprentice by Joseph Delany.

Examples:

1. Got what I need, you have.
2. Bossy and arrogant, he is.
3. Try to help her, I did.

Comment: Are you asking under what circumstances this is done because it's not a common construction?

Comment: We don't, ordinarily, but Yoda never learned to put the tensed verb in the main clause, right after the subject.

Comment: @Api Api did you read these expressions in a book? If so, please [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/496235/edit)  tell us its title and the name of its author. If they come from a film,  give us this information too IN your question NOT in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @GregLee The first example sounds quite wrong but the other phrases sound as if they are a form of dated Cockney or another outdated British English dialect.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Outdated British English dialect"? That's rather tendentious. Cockney? I'm not sure about that. Sounds more like Welsh, it does. It's sometimes called "focus fronting" or "predicate fronting".

Comment: @RosieF it wasn't meant to be insulting, just voicing an opinion. The structure sounds a bit dated to my ears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What term can be used to describe Yoda's speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/what-term-can-be-used-to-describe-yodas-speech). An example given: 'Help you I will.'

Comment: @RosieF. Yes, Focus-fronting. The accent is broadly Mancunian and the construction is relatively common in the North in general. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wardstone_Chronicles. "The Wardstone Chronicles, published as The Last Apprentice series in the U.S., is a dark fantasy series of books written by British author Joseph Delaney". [...] The County" referenced in the Chronicles is based on Lancashire in the North of England."

Answer (score 0):

It's much more likely that the verb would be *repeated* at the end of the sentence by way of emphasis - "You're cute, you are" (to a baby or pet animal) - "I'm Henery the Eighth, I am." - "She's a great cook, she is."

Answer (score 0):

It sounded like the writer paraphrased it in his own creative way, like how he would have narrated it in movies. (Written vs Spoken English)

1. Do you have what I need? Yes.
2. Is he bossy and arrogrant? Yes.
3. Did I try to help her? Yes.