# What is the term for moving an adjective from before to after the noun it describes?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I think this is a bit of an anachronism, but sometimes in nursery rhymes or songs you'll hear sentences in which an adjective describing a noun is moved to be after the noun it describes, and I was wondering if there's a specific term for this. Examples:

"The little sheep black" instead of "The little black sheep"

"The virgin pure" instead of "The pure virgin"

Comment: They can be called ["**post-positioned** adjectives."](http://www.kiss.aaronsimbeck.com/kiss/wb/LPlans/WB_L5_5_PPA.htm)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/what-term-can-be-used-to-describe-yodas-speech/25861#25861)

Comment: Possible a duplicate: [Is 'the city beautiful' – Orlando's motto – grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28493/is-the-city-beautiful-orlandos-motto-grammatically-correct/28507#28507), at least in spirit. The (broader) terms, for unusual word order, are given there.

Comment: @FF Isn't that term usually reserved for those adjectives that are usually found after the noun?

Answer (score 1):

It's a form of *[inversion](https://literarydevices.net/inversion/)*, also known as an *anastrophe*.

> Inversion, also known as “anastrophe,” is a literary technique in
>   which the normal order of words is reversed, in order to achieve a
>   particular effect of emphasis or meter.

Comment: Be careful: in some contexts the term *inversion* refers only to placing the sentence's verb before that verb's subject, not to the rearrangement of any other syntactic elements.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, the reference at the link cites that case.