# Unusual word order in a sentence

Tags: word-order, hyperbaton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “xxxx doth not a yyyy make” considered valid English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/why-is-xxxx-doth-not-a-yyyy-make-considered-valid-english)
>   [Proper usage/origin of the generic phrase “[action phrase] does not a [noun] make”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52596/proper-usage-origin-of-the-generic-phrase-action-phrase-does-not-a-noun-mak)
>   [“Two films don't a revolution make”: is this sentence grammatically correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58102/two-films-dont-a-revolution-make-is-this-sentence-grammatically-correct)
>   [“Dazzling images do not a shining nation make”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57128/dazzling-images-do-not-a-shining-nation-make)
>   [Is employing hyperbaton correct in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25508/is-employing-hyperbaton-correct-in-english)

The following sentence is from the book "Practical Common Lisp":

> A single record, however, does not a database make.

It sounds somewhat strange because of the word order: Subject-aux.verb-object-verb. Instead of this order I would expect the following:

> A single record, however, does not make a database.

Is this a common practice? Does the first order alter meaning in any way? Maybe it mimics some other text or a way of talking?

Comment: It's an archaic phrasing, with the main verb at the end of the clause, separated from its auxiliaries, as in Modern German. This is an [allusion to a famous sentence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make) in an early translation of Aristotle: "One swallow does not a summer make, nor one fine day; similarly one day or brief time of happiness does not make a person entirely happy."

Comment: @JohnLawler That's the definitive answer.

Comment: Aristotle pinched it off Yoda: "A summer one swallow does not make."

Comment: @JohnLawler That comment looks like an answer, and evidently a useful one: can you most kindly make it one?

Comment: There's also the famous couplet with the same structure in the beginning of the last stanza of "To Althea, From Prison", by Richard Lovelace in 1642: "_Stone walls do not a prison make,/Nor iron bars a cage._" It's a piece of Germanic syntax that didn't make the cut; evolution in action.