# "A place nearby" but not "A place good"

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I can ask any of:

> Do you know a breakfast place nearby?
>   Do you know a nearby breakfast place?
>   Do you know a good breakfast place?

but I really can't ask:

> Do you know a breakfast place good?

Is there a general rule for determining whether an adjective must come before the noun or may come, Spanish-style, after it?

Comment: In "a place nearby", *nearby* is not an adjective. And you've actually made the steps to verify that yourself, by substituting a different word that unmistakably is an adjective, and getting an ungrammatical result.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Oh? What word do you think it is that *nearby* applies to? It cannot apply to *know*, and you have scant few choices left. I see no difference between “a nearby breakfast place” and “a breakfast place nearby”.

Comment: Yet “Do you know a place good for late breakfasts?” works just fine.

Comment: @tchrist: in "a breakfast place nearby", *nearby* is an adverb of place. You can substitute it with *somewhere*, *here*, etc., or an adverbial phrase such as *in Moscow*. In your other example, "Do you know a place good for late breakfasts?", there is an omitted *that is* introducing a separate clause. It's a completely different construction altogether. That being said, things such as ["The city beautiful"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28493/is-the-city-beautiful-orlandos-motto-grammatically-correct) *are* possible in English.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA I do not deny that *nearby* describes a location. I just cannot see how you can think it is describing anything other than the word *place*.  Given that *nearby* is a modifier of the word *place*, and *place* is here a noun, then *nearby* is **by definition** here functioning as an adjective. What is your alternate reading? I know lots of ***nearby places***; how can that **not** be an adjective there?! Noun modifiers are never called adverbs, only adjectives.

Comment: @RegDwightA: I agree; but not that *do you know a place [that is] near by* probably contains the same elliptical construction originally.

Comment: @tchrist: That is a bold statement. In *a place in India*, it cannot be said that *in India* is an adjective. It is more complicated than that.

Comment: @Cerberus I stand my ground: in “I know lots of nearby places”, *nearby* is inarguably an adjective. As for your *place in India*, *in* is clearly a preposition, and the entire prepositional phrase is acting adjectivally **because it is modifying a noun**.

Comment: [This](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nearby?view=uk) clearly defines *nearby* as an adjective, just as I have been saying.

Comment: @tchrist: If *in India* were acting adjectivally, you'd be able to say, "I know an in India place".

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA No, that isn’t true; this is another example of John’s rule. In “I need a toy for little kids”, the prepositional phrase is acting adjectivally because it is attached to the noun *toy*. You cannot place it before the noun due to John’s rule, so “I need a ∗for little kids toy” is illegal. That doesn’t mean it isn’t a noun modifier; it certainly is.

Comment: @tchrist: My point is that "adjective" and "modifying a noun" are not exactly the same thing. I agree that "nearby" is unequivocally modifying "place" in "a nearby place", but it is perhaps not absurd to view it as an elliptical adjectival clause of which only the adverb is left ("I know this place [that is] nearby"). But I am not necessarily against calling it an adjective in "a nearby place": I merely have second thoughts about calling it an adjective in "a place nearby".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general rule is

> **One-word** modifiers precede the noun; modifiers **of more than one word** follow the noun.

I call this the [*Eleven-year-old boy* rule](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/209603/15299).

If you make a single word out of a phrase, it can precede (that's what the hyphens are for in writing), but it's got different syntax, because preceding adjectives are not declined for number.

Note the plural *years* and singular *year* below:

- *A boy eleven **years** old rescued the princess.*
- *An eleven-**year**-old boy rescued the princess.*

If you pluralized the second *year*, or used singular *year* in the first, they'd be ungrammatical.

*Nearby*, while it is enough of a single word to precede, still retains enough independence in its two consituents *near* and *by* to follow, as well. It's in transition from one state to the other.

Language changes, word by word and phrase by phrase, as we continue to speak it.
In fact, it changes **because** we continue to speak it.

Comment: Nice. I believe that that also explains why you can say “the boy within” but not “the ∗within boy”, versus “the boy ∗inner” being disallowed in favor of “the inner boy”. Right?

Comment: For a general rule which even copes with oddities like *nearby* this is beautifully elegant!

Comment: Your first example sentence itself is not-grammatical.  Instead: "A boy, eleven years old, rescued the princess."  You can see this if you take out the number: "A boy years old rescued the princess." The latter sentence doesn't work regardless of pluralization of 'years,' without adding commas.

Comment: True; that sentence is not grammatical. But _years old_ is not a constituent, while _eleven years_ and _eleven years old_ **are** constituents. One can't just delete numbers anywhere one wishes; syntactic rules only apply to constituents. Plus, punctuation is not present in language, only in writing, and has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: @NewAlexandria  You are mistaken: John’s own sentence is perfectly grammatical in English. “A boy eleven years old should be tall enough to play” and similar versions are perfectly fine.

Comment: I think this concept of a "general rule" is entirely contextual to a colloquial use of the language.  See my answer; I think that "Do you know a breakfast place nearby?" can be seen as a form that is in-use, but not the most essential presentation of the language.

Comment: @NewAlexandria ***“Colloquial”***? What are you talking about?  If you think it is somehow more correct to stick in a bunch of superfluous words, you are mistaken.

Comment: @tchrist - Probably s/he is talking about non-standard English.

Comment: @tchrist it is *not*.  'A boy eleven' is not a proper subject.  "Eleven years old" is a descriptor that is *optional*, and optional sentence-parts are wrapped in commas.

Comment: @NewAlexandria: the commas around 'eleven years old' are determined by whether it's a restrictive or non-restrictive clause; tchrist's example (unlike John Lawler's) was chosen so it ***must*** be a restrictive clause, which means you ***cannot*** put commas around it.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Utter nonsense. We’re talking about language here, not punctilious punctuational obsessions. You’re just making this stuff up.

Comment: A boy of eleven years should be tall enough to play.  A boy that is eleven years old should be tall enough to play.  A boy aged eleven years should be tall enough to play.  A boy eleven years old should be tall enough to play.   ....one of these things (the last one) is not like the other.  A restrictive clause is not *not* carte-blanche to drop parts of the sentence.

Comment: Doesn't the idiomatic expression 'nine days' wonder' provide an exception to the rule 'preceding adjectives are not declined for number' (and to the rule about the need to 'make a single word out of a phrase' before it may be used attributively)? Admittedly, I can't think of any other similar cases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Not really. It's a genitive, and the possessive _-'s_ cliticizes to the end of a full NP. The rule is about predicational ("adjective") modifiers, not possessives.

Comment: @John: I don't know if I'm imagining things, but might there be a tendency to speak the words more quickly when a "multi-word adjective" comes before the noun it modifies? It's been suggested this answer is relevant to [my hypothesis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155993/) that **"-ly adverb" + p.p. verb** adjectives are more likely to be hyphenated when the come before the noun. Perhaps the hypothesis is rubbish anyway - but if there *is* anything to it, could "speed of oral delivery" be a factor?

Answer (score -3):

You are missing the role of 'that/which' in proper grammatical construction:

#### The locations:

"Do you know a breakfast place, ***which is*** nearby?"

"Do you know a breakfast place ***that is*** nearby?"

"Do you know a nearby breakfast place?"

#### The qualities:

"Do you know a good breakfast place?"

to switch these, you must ask:

"Do you know a breakfast place ***that is*** good?"

"Do you know a breakfast place, ***which is*** good?"

Your question presents a wonderful example of what people often call a "problem" with the English language — which *in reality* is a problem with the colloquial **use** of the English language.

(p.s. in some sense *location* can present as much of a qualification as *food excellence*, but most people will not be so technical in their thinking)

Comment: What the heck are you talking about with this allegedly “proper” business?  You don’t somehow make a sentence more correct by sticking in a bunch of extra words.

Comment: Ah, you appear to be referring to the distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive [relative clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html). That distinction turns out not to be relevant in this case.

Comment: @tchrist your down-vote goes too far.  This usage is original, not the way that we have come to use the language (here in the US).  It *is* true that "Do you know a breakfast place that is good?" is correct grammar, and show the correct form of that arrangement, as sought by the OP

Comment: Looks like you got three downvotes, Alex my dear. Whom else are you planning to accuse? And what is this nutty “in the US” business about? You have a rotten sense for correctness and propriety and formalism and region, misleading you into saying completely ludicrous things. It is not some special characteristic of American English to speak colloquially or “improperly” as you seem to claim. Nor is what you call colloquial in any fashion substandard, abnormal, ungrammatical, or wrong. You’re just making stuff up.

Comment: I can't agree with this answer - it doesn't seem to cover the relevant point, which is that nearby can be used as an adjective or an adverb.

Comment: NewAlexandria, I downvoted because you were not in my opinion responsive to the main thrust of the question: that "Do you know a breakfast place nearby?" is undoubtedly a grammatical and complete sentence, but 'nearby' seems to land in a strange place for an adjective.

Comment: But which is it? "Eleven-year-old-boy rule" (a rule issued by an eleven-year-old boy) or "Eleven-year-old boy rule" (a boy rule that is eleven years old")? That's the question.