# "Today's news is tomorrow's history" -- are those possessives?

Tags: possessives

In the sentence above, why is "'s" used? Is it considered a possessive? It seems strange to state that the news "belongs" to today or the history "belongs" to tomorrow.

Comment: Closely related: [Should “two weeks vacation” be written “two weeks’ vacation” with a possessive apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/should-two-weeks-vacation-be-written-two-weeks-vacation-with-a-possessive-a?rq=1)

Comment: "Today's news" means "The news **of** this day (today)" If you replaced "today" with a proper noun or noun phrase you see why the possessive appostrophe is necessary "Peter's news" or "My brother's news"

Comment: They are genitive case nouns, of which possession is just one meaning. Your examples belong to a sub-type of 'attributive' genitive called 'descriptive' genitives -- other examples include "a summer's day" and "a Sainsbury's catalogue". Another sub-type is the 'measure' genitive, which includes such examples as "an hour's delay", "one dollar's worth of chocolates".

Comment: BillJ is right: in English, we often use "possessive" as the name of the case that is known as "genitive" in other languages, but actual possession is not the only thing that the case implies.

Answer (score -2):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> They are genitive case nouns, of which possession is just one meaning. Your examples belong to a sub-type of 'attributive' genitive called 'descriptive' genitives -- other examples include "a summer's day" and "a Sainsbury's catalogue". Another sub-type is the 'measure' genitive, which includes such examples as "an hour's delay", "one dollar's worth of chocolates".