# Is it "interest free" or "interest-free" when describing a loan without an interest rate?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

I watched a clip a show shown on TruTV about a woman who was angry about not having been offered free cash for thirty days.  According to the receptionist in the financial services place she was in, the sign she (the disgruntled customer) read meant that one can receive a loan free of interest within a 30-day span.  However, the sign reads:

> INTEREST LOANS
>      Bring a Friend to
>      American Jewelry and Loan
>      Get 30 days of interest free cash!

Notice the final line.  There's no hyphen between "interest" and "free," so isn't the customer's misunderstanding valid?  I'm assume that "interest" has to modify "free" in order to conjoin the words.

So, to remind you: When describing a loan that's free of interest (0% interest), is it "interest-free" or "interest free?"  I'm assuming it's the former.

For the record, I have googled this, and I came up with mixed results.  Some sites use "interest free" and others use "interest-free."

Comment: I would say this is googleable and I would use a dash: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=interest-free%2Cinterest+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share= - what is 30 days of interest? I would expect a comma if she wanted some interest in her person and free cash on top

Comment: Interestingly google shows the result as Interest Free but the page they got it from has it WITH the dash. One of the biggest British banks: http://www.natwest.com/global/glossary.ashx

Comment: haha, So you see why I asked then.  You'd think that there'd be a strict rule here.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The question you presented is too general for this thread to be a mirror image of it.

Comment: @mplungjan hyphen. Not dash. Using a dash there would be wrong.

Comment: dash, ndash, mdash, hyphen, whatever ;)

Comment: @Mr_Spock If you are asking about an isolated case, it is "too localized." If the answers to the duplicate question don't answer your question, then you can edit your question to explain why they are not sufficient and this question can be unduped. You'll have to do better than swearing at us though.

Comment: @Mr_Spock The onus is on you to demonstrate that it is neither too specific (we really don't need a question about every sign that might or might not need a hyphen on it) nor a duplicate of the other question. You haven't done that. If you edit your question to satisfy that requirement, it could easily be unduped.

Comment: We hyphenate "interest-free" in phrases such as "interest-free loans" at my magazine, but we don't hyphenate "interest free" in phrases such as "loans that are interest free." However, hyphenation of this type raises complicated issues and often involves arbitrary and idiosyncratic rules (and much confusion among writers). One issue is whether the phrase is so common that the intended audience will instantly recognize it; if so, the hyphen serves no useful function. For that reason, we don't hyphenate "word processing" in the phrase "word processing program" at my computer magazine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, normally a compound adjective would be formed by using a hyphen [this is the [“11-year-old boy rule”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76255/18696)].

However, if the term is actually “free cash” then two questions arise:

1. What is the word *interest* doing there?
2. What is *free cash* anyway?

If you get free cash for a period, implying that you have to pay it back, then it is free of interest. If it’s simply *free cash*, handed out willy-nilly, then the word *interest* makes no sense.

So: yes, strictly it’s wrong and there should be a hyphen. Realistically, it makes no difference.