# When to, and when not to pluralise month?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can someone please explain the correct way of pluralising month, for instance why do we sometimes use months or month, such as:

"Victor is a 7 month old baby"

and

"Victor is 7 months old"

What is the grammar behind this?

Comment: Perhaps suprisingly, the accepted answer at ["A place nearby" but not "A place good"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good) answers this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. '7 month old' is actually '7-month-old'. It serves as an attribute that modifies a noun. (e.g. *old* in *the old dog*.)

   It is adjectival and therefore has no plural form. You need to put an article in front of it and a noun after it.

   For example: *He is a 7-year-old boy*.
2. 'is 7 months old' is a predicate that states something about the subject. (e.g. *old* in *the dog is old*.)

   In this case, adding -s to the end of *year* is the proper and regular way.

   For example: *The boy is 7 years old*.

Answer (score -2):

> Victor is a 7 month old baby.

In that case, 'a' acts as a determiner before the term '7 month'.

But in this one,  '7 months' itself acts as a determiner.

> Victor is 7 months old.

Comment: No, the predicate is not a determiner in your second example.