# a thirty-billion-dollar swindle or a thirty-billion dollar swindle?

Tags: hyphenation

Is it hyphenated as 'a thirty-billion-dollar swindle'  or 'a thirty-billion dollar swindle' ?

Comment: or, possibly no hyphen at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spelling out numbers in written dialogue](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154919/spelling-out-numbers-in-written-dialogue) (6) Joe said, "She displayed one hundred and ten percent commitment." etc.

Comment: Try "a $30 billion swindle."