# Is there a dash between "n-second"

Tags: grammatical-number, dashes

Take the example "one-second interval". Is there a dash between "one" and "second"? Also, should second be plural if I say "three-second/s interval"?

Comment: John Lawler's answer mentioning the [eleven-year-old boy rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good) answers this.

Comment: BTW, maybe it should be called a *hyphen*, not a *dash*.