# Correct use of year/years old

Tags: common-word

On my profile I wrote:

```
I'm 19 years old developer.
```

my friend respectfully corrected me and said that this is correct form:

```
I'm 19 year old developer.
```

Why is that so?

Comment: What's **a** [developer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developer)? Is it to do with real estate or software?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and should be migrated to ELL i.e. [English language learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is already [a relevant answer on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good/76255#76255).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plural is used to describe **you** so:

*I am 19 years old.*

is correct

The singular is used to describe **developer** so:

*I am a 19 year old developer.*

or

*I am a 19-year-old developer.*

is correct.

This is similar to:

*This is a 19 year old bottle of wine.*

or

*This is a 19-year-old bottle of wine.*

Comment: Hyphens are normal with a premodifier.

Comment: I agree and have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget the article 'a': I am **a** 19-year-old developer.

Your friend is right. We also say a five pound note, a three mile run, an eight ounce steak, a ten ton truck etc. Why? They are compound nouns and are effectively singular; also adjectives in English are invariable and these extra modifying words are behaving like adjectives. In the plural, they would take an 's': 6 five pound notes, 5 three mile runs, 4 eight ounce steaks, 3 ten ton trucks and two 19-year-old developers.