# "3-month retreat" or "3-months retreat"?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english

Which one is the correct (or more commonly used) form: "3-month retreat" or "3-months retreat"?  How about "3-day" vs. "3-days" and "3-week" vs. "3-weeks" in the same context? (This is retreat as in meditation retreat and for U.S. English.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, you'd use the singular. So "3 day weekend" or "8 week course" or, yes, "3 month retreat".

Comment: +1 And no hyphen either?

Comment: @Drux there's no particularly consistent rule there, IIRC. The hyphen is not incorrect, nor is it's omission.

Comment: There is a consistent rule for hyphens, it's just people who are not consistent about using it. Search for related questions.

Comment: @Neeku Thx. I'm usually applying rules from *The Elements of Style* which (if memory serves) would recommend one (but not two) hyphens. (Any rule better be consistent :)

Comment: Yes @Drux. If each adjective alone doesn't make sense being used with the noun, then you **must** use a hyphen. Neither "*8 course*" nor "*week course*" make sense, so "8-week course" is correct. Obviously no hyphen is needed between the adjective and the noun.

Comment: @Neeku I was struggling with "more commonly used form" (see above), and there (perhaps inconsistently) decided against hyphens :)

Comment: Right @Drux, but going with the common mistakes isn't a good practice. Always stick to the correct form, and avoid spreading the common mistakes more than before. Watching "WordCrimes" is highly recommended. (:

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps surprisingly, the accepted answer at ["A place nearby" but not "A place good"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good) answers this. However, that question title is not an intuitive match for this problem, and the relevant sentence is a bit buried.

In the phrase *3-month retreat,* the main noun is *retreat* and *three-month* serves as an adjective (or an attributive noun, I suppose). Because it has more than one word, a hyphen is necessary to keep all the parts of that adjective together. Because it's an adjective, it remains *month* and not *months:* **preceding adjectives are not inflected for number.**

This serves for other similar collocations:

- a six-foot coffin
- a ten-year-old boy
- a fifty-six-page book

Comment: +1 for digging this up and for citing an explicit rule.