# An over-the-top, gauntlets-thrown, when-is-it-appropriate-to-hyphenate debate

Tags: hyphenation, sic

An eye-glazingly, mind-numbingly boring debate is raging on usmessageboard.com over hyphenation. One user posted

> full-throttle, out-of-the-gate, naked attempt by the press

to which another user responded

> Has any other POTUS " out-of-the-gate" [sic] preceded and commenced their presidency

which the first user took as an attack on his grammar, and, well, the to-hyphenate-or-not-to-hyphenate debate has raged ever since.

In an attempt to restore the tranquility of the board and its usual civil tone, I offered to submit an appeal for arbitration here.

The question mentioned of which mine may be a duplicate does indeed answer many of the points raised in the battle raging elsewhere, but doesn't address others, which I will try to list below. Nor does it cover the [sic] aspect of our controversy. I realize the question could be split into two separate questions, but that would reduce the chance our community would receive the fairest possible judgment from our community.

And that brings up the objection below to the appeal for arbitration. I imagine there are any number of reasons someone might post a question here. Some, I suppose, are composing an email at work their boss will see, and they want to be as precise as possible so that they make a good impression. Others may be working on a thesis they are going to present and want to be sure of their lingual footing during the orals. Another might be composing a letter to a cheating lover and she wants to express her broken heart in a crystal clear voice free of any quaver an ungrammatical sentence would give it. We neither ask them the reason, nor sanction them if they offer the reason.

I offered the reason because I thought it was a light-hearted and inoffensive addition to my question without detracting from it.

The aspects of this question that weren't addressed in the other's answer, thorough as it was:

1. Since hyphenation is to be used to form a compound word immediately preceding a noun, out-of-the-gate should not have been hyphenated because of the interposition of the word "naked" between the adjectival phrase and the modified noun, "attempt". The OP responded that the stack of adjectives all qualified as immediately preceding the noun;
2. The temporal quality of "out of the gate" made it adverbial and thus undeserving of a hyphen. In response, the OP maintained "out-of-the-gate" was indeed adjectival;
3. The [sic] was not a criticism of the OP's grammar, but a defense against the possibility the OP's mistake would be imputed to the respondent.

So there you have it. Was this a mistake?

> full-throttle, out-of-the-gate, naked attempt by the press

Comment: Instead of giving us the history of a debate on a discussion forum elsewhere, could you please formulate a clear question for this English Language question and answer site. This is not an arbitration tribunal. If you formulate a decent question you may get some decent answers, the merits of which you and your friends can judge for themselves. For the moment I am voting to close your question as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi! Rules of hyphenation are a great subject for this site. But I think your question will probably be answered (and quite competently so) by John Hanna's answer here: [When to use a hyphen to coin a new word and when to omit a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100818/when-to-use-a-hyphen-to-coin-a-new-word-and-when-to-omit-a-hyphen) If that doesn't answer your question, could you perhaps edit it to clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: While the new sentence is better without the hyphens, the writer has a right to quote verbatim, hyphens and all. What I don't get is *preceded* instead of *any other preceding POTUS*.

Comment: I agree re: clarifying the question _and_ I enjoyed the OP's wry wit.

Comment: “Since hyphenation is to be used to form a compound word immediately preceding a noun” — Where are you getting this from? It’s not true, and never has been. Hyphens are frequently used in certain types of compounds when they’re used **attributively** (as opposed to predicatively). Whether or not anything comes between the compound and what they modify is irrelevant.

Comment: I do not understand why you keep bringing up grammar. Hyphens are not grammar and have nothing to do with grammar. There are no hyphens in speech. Can you please kill all mentions of grammar, they are not helping at all in making your question viable. Thanks.

Comment: @ RegDwigнt  What are they? Punctuation?

Comment: @RegDwigнt [I often wonder why people use names that are not easily typed by others] I agree, hyphens are not grammar. Hyphens depend on the "style sheet" one has in one's head or the style sheet belonging to those for whom one works....that said, adjectivally compound phrases are usually hyphenated when pre-positioned and not when post positioned....

Comment: There's an example of sequential hyphenated prenominal compound adjectives at [Use of hyphens in a compound adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249108/use-of-hyphens-in-a-compound-adjective).

Answer (score 0):

> He gave a full throttle performance.

Did he give a full performance of a throttle; or did he give a performance that was full throttle?

> He gave a full-throttle performance

Now it's clear which one is meant.

---

Especially on this site, you often see [block parentheses] to denote how a sentence should be parsed. E.g.

> He gave a [full throttle] performance.

However, these parentheses are only accepted when analyzing the sentence structure, not in normal communication.

This phenomenon of hyphenation-for-clarity **does** seem to be accepted in normal communication; and its intention is the same: **to assist the reader with correctly parsing the sentence**.

Logically speaking, they are therefore only really necessary in cases where there is ambiguity. If there is no ambiguity, they are not necessary (from a functional perspective at least. From a grammatical perspective, they may always be required so that the usage remains consistent).

Comment: How about from a stylistic perspective? Can it be argued that the hyphens add a certain panache to the writing?

Comment: @CWill: In my opinion, not really. The hyphens are added for clarity, not style. However, you can argue that _choosing to use long-winded descriptions_ (which require hyphenation) **is** a stylistic choice. But that is different from _why_ the hyphens are warranted.

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, I am the person who wrote the sentence containing the "[sic]."  CWill accurately expressed my reason for doing so.

The complete sentence CWill wrote is:  "There has never been a full-throttle, out-of-the-gate, naked attempt by the press to bring down a president like we are witnessing here."

In my response to him, among other things, I wrote:  "Has any other POTUS 'out-of-the-gate' [sic] preceded and commenced their presidency with the nature and extent of utter BS Trump has?"

I included "[sic]" because of the following:

- "Out of the box" is an accepted idiom that is classified as an adverbial prepositional phrase; thus it does not need hyphenation.
- To give "out of of the box" the linguistic function of an adjectival prepositional phrase in a sentence, one must hyphenate it; however, in doing so, one also must place it immediately before the noun/pronoun it modifies.  The reason one must so place the adjectival variant of the phrase derives from adverbs being appropriately placed either before and after the words they modify, whereas adjectives customarily, though not universally, precede the words they modify.  As far as I know, one should adhere to same sequencing convention for adjectival and adverbial phrases as that of simple adjectives and adverbs.  Similarly, readers are expected to use the same convention for comprehending what they read.

The fact that I included "[sic]" is what bothered CWill.  The discussion about idioms, adjectival and adverbial phrases, along with my not wanting readers to construe that I'd hyphenated "out of the box," is what I shared with CWill as my reasons for writing "[sic]."

The specific question of grammar/spelling is whether hyphenating "out of the box" in CWill's original sentence is correct.  Obviously, insofar as I used "sic" when I quoted his phrase, I think it is not.

Comment: The hyphenations were fine: "a full-throttle, out-of-the-gate, naked attempt". Compare that to: "a full-throttle, out of the gate, naked attempt". The latter is a mistake. It  has to come before the noun, but who says it must immediately  precede it? Yours could have been: "Has any other POTUS preceded and commenced their presidency "out of the gate" with the nature and extent of utter BS Trump has?" No hyphens, and correctly placed in your sentence.  No need to sic it at all. Just use quotes to show where it came from.

Comment: FYI: stackexchange is not a forum and answers are not "posts."

Comment: @Cascabel: **What is the purpose of the Not an Answer flag?** To identify attempts by community members to use answers for any purpose other than answering questions.( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/ )

Comment: @Yorik I was only taking exception to the phrase "answers are not "posts" .It could be mis-interpreted. The word "post" is used quite liberally throughout SE.

Comment: The 'Generally, hyphenate any non-solid prenominal compound adjectives, especially nonce examples' rule applies, as shown by [Yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/out-of-the-box), and the use of [sic] was thus incorrect. Note that '_immediately_ preceding the noun' is inaccurate here as it fails to consider stacked prenominal adjectives.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet asked, "“Since hyphenation is to be used to form a compound word immediately preceding a noun” — Where are you getting this from?"  That guideline is found here:  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+box .

Comment: @cascabel:  I'm sorry.  I don't follow.  Clicking on the link you provided, I see the following:  
Prepositional phrase
Used other than as an idiom: See out of, the, box.
(idiomatic, of a product) Immediate(ly), without intervention from the customer.
This software has to work out of the box, without any fancy installation.
(idiomatic) Outside the box; unconventional(ly): outside the limits of conventional thinking.

Comment: Xelor: not my link. It was from Edwin.

Comment: Another example of the "immediately before the noun" hyphenation of compound adjectival prepositional phrases can be found here:  http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp.  I'm sticking with the "immediately before" approach because everywhere I look, I see it presented that way.

Comment: Apologies, Cascabel

Comment: Here is yet another illustration of the model whereby compound adjectival prepositional phrases are hypenated when they immediately preced the noun they modify:  http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf.

Comment: The relevant part was << Prepositional phrase: out-of-the-box

Alternative form of out of the box. (especially in attributive use) >>

There are three adjectives (one compound) used attributively in 'the smelly old bottle-green socks'.

Comment: 'Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea.' I see no 'immediately' here. // Likewise with CMOS's 'Hyphenated before but not after a noun.' //// 'The quick-witted little boy saved the day.' and 'A good-looking young woman opened the door.' are surely sufficient proof for most people that the 'immediately before' needs correcting.

Comment: @edwinAshworth I direct you to the first of my bullet points.  "Good-looking" is already in our lexicon as an accepted and hyphenated idiom.  I'm not at all suggesting that one apply the "immediately before" convention for extant idioms, which "good-looking" and "out of the box" both are.