# Using a hyphen when describing measures (e.g., a 300-meter asteroid)

Tags: hyphenation, numbers, measuring-units

Here's some examples. Please tell me which ones are right, and which ones are wrong, and why.

1. "A 350-meter asteroid impacted the Moon."
2. "A 350-meters asteroid impacted the Moon."
3. "A 350 meter asteroid impacted the Moon."
4. "A 350 meters asteroid impacted the Moon."

There's also extended versions.

5. "A 350-meter wide asteroid impacted the Moon."
6. "A 350-meter-wide asteroid impacted the Moon."

Etcetera. Which ones are right/wrong, and why?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, an [answer on an apparently-unrelated question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good/76255?s=1|0.4511#76255) actually answers this. We are going to need that canonical answer on a more obviously-related question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach you don't need either of those hyphens.

Comment: Many people still disagree with "impact" as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

"A 350-meter asteroid impacted the Moon." is the right form.

"A 350-meter-wide asteroid impacted the Moon." is the right extended form.

Here you are combining two or more words to form a compound adjective in front of a noun and in this case, you need put a hyphen between these words.

We can also say ->

"A 350 meters wide asteroid impacted the Moon."

Here the number is not used as compound adjective preceding a noun and hence there is no need to hyphenate.

Comment: "A 350 meters wide asteroid" is incorrect.