# Hyphenation question

Tags: hyphenation

I've got a English tutor and we had a session on English writing.

But he gave me a correction on my writing which is still confusing to me.

> The practice lasted about three weeks, after which every team would do voice over in front of the class.

He said "three weeks" should/could be hyphenated, i.e "three-weeks."

That was confusing to me as I thought week is hyphenated in cases like

a three-week holiday.

Did my tutor give me a wrong answer or was it just me not knowing the rules?

Comment: Don't give him any cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis is correct. 'three-weeks' in that context is simply wrong. It is possible that the tutor confused this with the adjectival use.

*The practice lasted about three weeks.* [correct]

*The practice lasted about three-weeks.* [incorrect]

As you correctly say, we expect a hyphen when forming an adjective as in, "a three-week holiday".

*[Note: I edited this answer in deference to comments. I now see that my previous answer potentially  raised more problems than it solved.]*

---

**Note**

I would hyphenate 'voice-over' or write it as 'voiceover'.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "We did a three-week practice"? Hyphenated compounds are normally in the singular when they precede the noun e.g. "A three-year-old boy",  "A five-star hotel"

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes. Adjectives in English are not inflected for number.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/a-place-nearby-but-not-a-place-good/76255?s=7|0.3232#76255). *Three-week* is a one-word modifier, placed before a noun; because it's a one-word modifier, it's not inflected for number.

Comment: No, it's not different at all. Your "correct" *a three-weeks practice* is definitely wrong.

Comment: The OP himself prefers to write: **a three-week holiday.** It is the tutor who argues that *three-weeks* is correct in the predicative position.