# Placing the object of an infinitive before it instead of after it

Tags: verbs, word-order, legalese, rhetoric

> At the beginning of 1807, based on information gathered
>   from Burr’s correspondence allegedly showing that he had begun preparations for a large-scale
>   military expedition, the former vice president was arrested in Louisiana and indicted on the charge of
>   [“wickedly devising and intending ♦ the peace and tranquility of the same United States **to disturb** and to stir, move, and excite insurrection, rebellion and war against the said United States”](http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/burr/burrindictment.html)

Would someone please affirm the position of *to disturb* in the passage cited above? Am I right in thinking that it can equally be planted at ♦, as one might in contemporary English?

If correct, what’s this stylistic placement called? Also, what are its advantages or disadvantages? I find it more onerous and less lucid; I had to reread it to determine the infinitive.

Source: page 54 of *America on Trial*, by Alan Dershowitz

Comment: I replaced the embedded quotation from Dershowitz' book from the Indictment of Aaron Burr with the corresponding passage from the original, so as to remove the ellipse included by the original poster, which in my opinion, introduced too much ambiguity to allow the original poster's question to be answered.

Comment: Looks like a rhetorical device to get the damning words **disturb, stir, move, and excite** all together in a row for best results when spoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct as written.

It is a stylistic choice used to draw attention to some portion of the sentence. This is the rhetorical device called ***anastrophe***, itself a type of ***hyperbaton***.  *Anastrophe* is defined by the OED as:

> Inversion, or unusual arrangement, of the words or clauses of a sentence.

### Poetic Use

As mentioned [here](https://mcl.as.uky.edu/glossary-rhetorical-terms#5), Coleridge uses this device in [*The Rime of the Ancient Mariner*](http://www.ram.org/contrib/rime_ancient_mariner.html), where the more common word-order of *a breeze never blew up* is replaced by *never a breeze up-blew*:

> *The helmsman steered, the ship moved on;
>
>   Yet **never a breeze up-blew**;
>
>   The mariners all ’gan work the ropes,
>
>   Where they were wont to do;
>
>   They raised their limbs like lifeless tools—
>
>   We were a ghastly crew.*

He could have written *A breeze never blew up* instead, but that would have thrown off the meter.

Another example of this, again drawn from the same poem, is:

> *And the bay was white with silent light,
>
>   Till rising from the same,
>
>   Full many shapes, that shadows were,
>
>   **In crimson colours came.***

Coleridge uses anastrophe quite a bit in his poetry.  Consider the opening lines from his poem [“Kubla Khan”](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173247):

> *In Xanadu **did Kubla Khan
>
>   A stately pleasure-dome decree**:
>
>   Where Alph, the sacred river, ran 
>
>   Through caverns measureless to man 
>
>      Down to a sunless sea.*

Without placing *pleasure-dome* before *decree*, he could not have rhymed it with *sea* later on.  Even modern poets writing in rhyme still do this sort of thing all the time. In his short poem about [Eärendil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%A4rendil),
JRR Tolkien uses anastrophe at several points in this single stanza:

> *[**A ship then new they built** for him
>
>   of mithril and of elvenglass](http://linux4u.jinr.ru/usoft/WWW/www_perl.com/perl/divert/source_quotes.html)
>
>   with crystal keel; no shaven oar
>
>   nor sail she bore, on silver mast
>
>   the Silmaril as lantern light
>
>   and banner bright with living flame
>
>   of **fire unstained** by Elbereth
>
>   herself was set, who thither came
>
>   and **wings immortal made** for him,
>
>   and laid on him undying doom,
>
>   to sail the shoreless skies and come
>
>   behind the Sun and light of Moon.*

If you rearrange all the anastrophic orderings, you get something more like:

> Then they built a new ship for him of mithril and of elvenglass with
>   crystal keel.  She bore no shaven oar nor sail. The Silmaril was set on
>   silver mast by Elbereth herself as a lantern light and a bright banner with
>   living flame of unstained fire.  She came thither and made immortal wings
>   for him and laid on him undying doom: to sail the shoreless skies and come
>   behind the Sun and the Moon’s light.

Doesn’t sound so nice anymore, does it?

### Prose Use

Using OSV or SOV ordering instead of SVO ordering was formerly more common in English than it is today.  The ritual marriage vows of *With this ring **I thee wed*** and *till **death do us part*** both place the object before the verb instead of after it.  This SOV ordering still happens all the time in related languages like Dutch and German, but in English it can sound archaizing to the modern ear.

Nonetheless, it does still get used, and not just for poetry alone, either. Although anastrophe is at times used purely for the meter’s sake (as it here seems to be in Coleridge), at other times it is used to pull important words up to the front of their phrase so as to draw attention to them.

In rhetoric, anastrophic rearrangements have other purposes than for the sake of the meter, since in prose there is (well, in theory) no meter to serve.   It can be done purely for emphasis, like saying *More money you will never get from me.*

In the Burr indictment, it seems to have been done to keep certain words and phrases close to each other for increased effect.  It clusters the infinitives together without risking an object separating them. *To disturb and to stir* certainly belong together like that, but if you had put the object of *disturb* after the verb, you would have an unsightly wedge driven between the related infinitives — **or** you would have driven an unsightly wedge between the related verbs; your choice. :)

[Fronting the object like that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization) places the focus of the verb on the 
object.  This isn’t really “inversion poetical” so much as it is using simple matters of word order to control the emphasis.  See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78595) for a longer citation regarding using word-order emphatically; it is something that is natural in English.

Fronting isn’t as strange as you might think; it happens with relative clauses all the time, like saying *This is the man I told you about*.

The advantage of anastrophe is that you notice it.  That may also be its disadvantage if you aren’t prepared for such parses.  That is, it may cause the unsophisticated reader to temporarily misparse the sentence.

But gee whiz, when you are talking about **a single sentence that’s one thousand two hundred and six words long** the way [the Aaron Burr indictment](http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/burr/burrindictment.html) is, greater problems of clarity than might be caused by mere anastrophe alone shall surely baffle the reader.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this is an older usage. It looks like the object was fronted or "topicalized" to the front of the infinitive. This no longer works in English but I guess it used to! Similar rules exist is German and other Germanic languages.

Answer (score 0):

Searching through Google Books and then again through Google for the phrase "intending * to disturb" (that is, for the word "intending" followed by the phrase "to disturb", optionally separated by other words), I got three types of result:

1. *intending to disturb*
2. *intending [adverb or adverbial phrase] to disturb*; for example "intending not to disturb", "intending in every respect to disturb"
3. *intending [conjunction] [present progressive verb] to disturb*; for example "intending and contriving to disturb", "intending or acting to deliberately disturb" (which has an adverb obtruding into the infinitive, but that's not my object of investigation)

I have not seen any other instances of the usage *intending [direct object of 'disturb'] to disturb*. You are correct in thinking that the typical modern usage would be to insert the infinitive where you placed the diamond.

Does Dershowitz' book cite the author of the quoted statement? It might be a usage peculiar to that author; or it might be a usage that was common in legal English at that time, but which Google Books (for example) simply has no other record of.

Comment: The citation is from [the indictment against Aaron Burr as read at his trial on August 17, 1807](http://law2.umkc.edu/faculty/projects/ftrials/burr/burrindictment.html).