# question about inverting adjectives(fronting)

Tags: adjectives, fronting

Can the sentence 'Fast and convenient are the laundry rooms on the second floor' also be used as 'Fast and convenient the laundry rooms are on the second floor'? I wanted to ask if this sentence structure is allowed when inverting adjectives to the front of a sentence.

Comment: Depends.  Are you trying to sound like Yoda?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: No, it's not normal sentence structure. That's why Yoda sounds weird to us, he talks like this.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78595/2085