# What is it? "So live with it you will"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, speech

```
So live with it you will
```

I wonder how this structure called, when "will" or "shall" are put at the end of the sentence. Is it just re-arrangement of parts or has any special name? Is it only recommended for spoken english?

I've heard this in one of Letterman's episodes (TV show)

Comment: Your example is "only recommended" if it follows *the same statement* made in standard SVO sequence: *You said you'd do it [**if** some situation arose, which it has], **so do it you will***. It's a somewhat "literary" device, so arguably it's actually more likely to arise in a written context than a spoken one). Don't generalize the principle, or talk like Yoda you will.

Comment: It's a simple re-ordering of the words in the sentence that provides an emphasis on the imperative or predictive  nature of what might otherwise be read in the simple future tense. It is like saying "So you ***will*** live with it."

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Very true. English is often 1% knowing what to say, and 99% knowing when and to/by whom...

Comment: I think this is an example of *inversion*. In other languages (Russian, for example) there is no strict word order so "inversions" are everywhere to nuance the meaning. In English, inversions are rare, mostly confined to written work, and hence carry more punch.

Comment: @A.S., Rob_Ster: Part of the reason for the inversion in OP's example is nicely illustrated by Rob's paraphrasing with stress on ***will***. What we *really* want to emphasize is the main verb itself (not the modal or the subject), so ***in a spoken context*** we might well prefer to put that element (*live with it*, or *in a spoken context*) immediately after the contextually significant conjunction ***so***.

Comment: Of related interest: *[Is employing hyperbaton correct in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25508)* and *[What term can be used to describe Yoda's speech?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25858/)*

Comment: It's Yoda-speak for "So you will live with it."  (If you heard it on Letterman it very likely was an intentional parody of Yoda.)

Comment: Thanks everybody. I am aware of Yoda-speak, but usually it involves some Force-hand-waving and low tone of voice. Hence, think of Yoda didn't I.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is there a way I can edit question so that it become more useful for E@SE and get an actual answer (from you, for example) I can accept?

Comment: aaaaaa: I think @A.S.'s comment above is telling. I'd be more than happy to answer a question like this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) - though I personally wouldn't even have *known* that point about word-order in Russian, which I think is important information in this context. But the bare fact that it's called "inversion" should really be common knowledge to the target user base on ELU.